# How to run a spray server on heroku with Scala 2.10?

Tags: heroku, sbt, scala-2.10, spray

I've created a Spray app with a simple REST service. I've followed a variation of the [instructions provided by heroku](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/scala). Variations:

- used `sbt.version=0.12.0`
- used `Build.scala` instead of build.sbt
- used spray instead of finagle

Long story short, I've got it running locally with little problems, also using foreman. Then I tried to push to heroku and the build fails horribly with variating unresolved dependencies caused by 503's, for example:

```
      http://s3pository.heroku.com/maven-central/net/java/dev/jna/jna/3.2.3/jna-3.2.3.jar

            ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::

            ::              FAILED DOWNLOADS            ::

            :: ^ see resolution messages for details  ^ ::

            ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::

            :: net.java.dev.jna#jna;3.2.3!jna.jar

            ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::


   :::: ERRORS
    SERVER ERROR: Service Unavailable url=http://s3pository.heroku.com/maven-central/net/java/dev/jna/jna/3.2.3/jna-3.2.3.pom.sha1
```

What's the cause of this and what can I do to get this running?

Comment: I think this is an issue with Heroku because I'm having exactly the same problem. It is intermittent. From some reading I've been doing, this is not the first time this sort of problem has arisen and, sadly, it can sometimes take many hours before anything is done about it :-(

Comment: Did you make it work ?

Comment: @ruslan yeah it started working once the heroku repo servers came back online. See my answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This was/is an issue with Heroku. Symptoms to know that it's not your fault:

- trivial dependencies like jna fail to download intermittently
- dependency resolution is dead slow

Go out and do something fun, or try a different PaaS cloud, and then try again after a few hours. In all likelihood things are back up and running by then.